# Vue.js 2 - removing items from array with event hub

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs2

I am using Vue.js 2 with Laravel and I have a method inside one component where I send a delete request to the server, and emit the event inside the vue app.
This is the method:

```
deleteAction() {
  let url = `extras/delete/${this.id}`;
  axios.delete(url);
  this.$eventHub.$emit('extras.delete', this.id);
  this.modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

And in the other component I am listening to the event and removing the item from the array of items that I use to render those items in the template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" class="media row">
      <div class="media-left col-sm-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" :src="item.image_path" :alt="item.title">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body col-sm-6">
        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ item.title }}</h4>
        <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 action-buttons">
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="/extras/create" role="button">Rediger</a>
        <alert :id="item.id"></alert>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['items'],
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  created() {
      this.$eventHub.$on('extras.delete',(id) => {
          this.items = this.items.filter(function(el) {
            return el.id !== id;
          });
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

But, even though I see the event happening in the debug tools under the events, the first item is only removed after the second attempt, and the all other items after the first one are removed normally with the first attempt. Why is this happening?

Comment: You shouldn't modify a prop directly. Better is to assign the prop to local data and mutate it then. Could be it's happening because of that.

Comment: ah, see there was an answer already. But that with mutating props is valid.

Comment: Yes, thank you I have changed that as well now.

Comment: Cool! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding key attribute. check the docs for more details https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" class="media row">
      <div class="media-left col-sm-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" :src="item.image_path" :alt="item.title">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body col-sm-6">
        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ item.title }}</h4>
        <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 action-buttons">
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="/extras/create" role="button">Rediger</a>
        <alert :id="item.id"></alert>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put console.log inside the created handle and event subscriber method and check if you are getting the desired id for the first time.